# Vagrant not booting unless im on the home path

Tags: ruby, virtualbox, vagrant

Vagrant is not booting unless im on the home path.

```
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~ cat Vagrantfile 
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
end
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~ vagrant up
[default] Importing base box 'precise32'...
[default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the install version of
VirtualBox! This may cause things such as forwarded ports, shared
folders, and more to not work properly. If any of those things fail on
this machine, please update the guest additions and repackage the
box.

Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
VirtualBox Version: 4.1.12
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~ vagrant destroy
Are you sure you want to destroy the 'default' VM? [Y/N] Y
[default] Forcing shutdown of VM...
[default] Destroying VM and associated drives...
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~
```

It boots successfully when I run `vagrant up` from my home path. But when I run `vagrant up` from another sub directory, its doesn't boot. Its kinda weird because the Vagrantfile which I use is exactly the same.

```
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~ 
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~ cd dev_vm 
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~/dev_vm cat Vagrantfile 
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
end
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~/dev_vm vagrant up
[default] VM already created. Booting if it's not already running...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
The VM failed to remain in the "running" state while attempting to boot.
This is normally caused by a misconfiguration or host system incompatibilities.
Please open the VirtualBox GUI and attempt to boot the virtual machine
manually to get a more informative error message.
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~/dev_vm 
[ruby-1.9.3-p286] ~/dev_vm
```

I even tried booting it manually from the Virtualbox UI, but I just see a blank screen. I probably think i'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export VAGRANT_LOG=debug`, this showed me a message to try out `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up`. And then my VM booted properly. Still weird to understand what could be the problem.

Comment: Did it really fix it for good? On my system, the problem you described in your post above appears to happen entirely randomly. It only happens with the precise32 box, though, so maybe the box itself is borked?

Answer (score 2):

I also want to add that you will get this error

> Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
>   The VM failed to remain in the "running" state while attempting to boot.
>   This is normally caused by a misconfiguration or host system incompatibilities.
>   Please open the VirtualBox GUI and attempt to boot the virtual machine
>   manually to get a more informative error message.

when running vagrant, if you've installed the i386 version of virualbox when you are on a 64bit processor.  So, make sure you have the correct virtualization software installed for your host machine.

Comment: I got this message when I've added 64bit version of raring onto 32bit virtualbox on my mac. Replacing it with 32bit version of raring fixed it.